# How to sample without replacement and reweigh each time (conditional sampling)?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, performance, pandas, numpy

Consider a dataset of N rows with weights. This is the basic algorithm:

1. Normalize the weights so that they sum to 1.
2. Backup the weights into another column to record sample probabilities
3. Randomly choose 1 row (without replacement), given the sample probabilities, and add it to the sample dataset
4. Remove the drawn weight from the original dataset, and recompute the sample probabilities by normalizing the weights of the remaining rows
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 till sum of weights in sample reaches or exceeds threshold (assume 0.6)

Here is a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def sampler(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n), columns=['weight'])
    df['weight'] = df['weight']/df['weight'].sum()
    df['samp_prob'] = df['weight']

    samps = pd.DataFrame(columns=['weight'])

    while True:
        choice = np.random.choice(df.index, 1, replace=False, p=df['samp_prob'])[0]
        samps.loc[choice, 'weight'] = df.loc[choice, 'weight']
        df.drop(choice, axis=0, inplace=True)
        df['samp_prob'] = df['weight']/df['weight'].sum()
        if samps['weight'].sum() >= 0.6:
            break
    return samps
```

The problem with the toy example is the exponential growth in run times with increasing size of `n`:

[image: Exponential Growth]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Starting off approach

Few observations  :

- The dropping of rows per iteration that results in creation of new dataframes isn't helping with the performance.
- Doesn't look like easy to vectorize, BUT should be easy to work with the underlying array data for performance. The idea would be to use masks and avoid re-creating dataframes or arrays. Starting off, we would be using two columns array, corresponding to the columns named : `'weights'` and `'samp_prob'`.

So, with those in mind, the starting approach would be something like this -

```
def sampler2(n):
    a = np.random.rand(n,2)
    a[:,0] /= a[:,0].sum()
    a[:,1] = a[:,0]
    N = len(a)

    idx = np.arange(N)
    mask = np.ones(N,dtype=bool)
    while True:
        choice = np.random.choice(idx[mask], 1, replace=False, p=a[mask,1])[0]
        mask[choice] = 0
        a_masked = a[mask,0]
        a[mask,1] = a_masked/a_masked.sum()
        if a[~mask,0].sum() >= 0.6:
            break
    out = a[~mask,0]
    return out
```

#### Improvement #1

A later observation revealed that the first column of the array isn't changing across iterations. So, we could optimize for the masked summations for the first column, by pre-computing the total summation and then at each iteration, `a[~mask,0].sum()` would be simply the total summation minus `a_masked.sum()`. Thsi leads us to the first improvement, listed below -

```
def sampler3(n):
    a = np.random.rand(n,2)
    a[:,0] /= a[:,0].sum()
    a[:,1] = a[:,0]
    N = len(a)

    idx = np.arange(N)
    mask = np.ones(N,dtype=bool)
    a0_sum = a[:,0].sum()
    while True:
        choice = np.random.choice(idx[mask], 1, replace=False, p=a[mask,1])[0]
        mask[choice] = 0
        a_masked = a[mask,0]
        a_masked_sum = a_masked.sum()
        a[mask,1] = a_masked/a_masked_sum
        if a0_sum - a_masked_sum >= 0.6:
            break
    out = a[~mask,0]
    return out
```

#### Improvement #2

Now, slicing and masking into the columns of a 2D array could be improved by using two separate arrays instead, given that the first column wasn't changing between iterations. That gives us a modified version, like so -

```
def sampler4(n):
    a = np.random.rand(n)
    a /= a.sum()
    b = a.copy()
    N = len(a)

    idx = np.arange(N)
    mask = np.ones(N,dtype=bool)
    a_sum = a.sum()
    while True:
        choice = np.random.choice(idx[mask], 1, replace=False, p=b[mask])[0]
        mask[choice] = 0
        a_masked = a[mask]
        a_masked_sum = a_masked.sum()
        b[mask] = a_masked/a_masked_sum
        if a_sum - a_masked_sum >= 0.6:
            break
    out = a[~mask]
    return out
```

**Runtime test -**

```
In [250]: n = 1000

In [251]: %timeit sampler(n) # original app
     ...: %timeit sampler2(n)
     ...: %timeit sampler3(n)
     ...: %timeit sampler4(n)
1 loop, best of 3: 655 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 50 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 44.9 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 38.4 ms per loop

In [252]: n = 2000

In [253]: %timeit sampler(n) # original app
     ...: %timeit sampler2(n)
     ...: %timeit sampler3(n)
     ...: %timeit sampler4(n)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.32 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 134 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 100 ms per loop
```

Thus, we are getting **`17x+`** and **`13x+`** speedups with the final version over the original method for `n=1000` and `n=2000` sizes!

Comment: Awesome! I had a strong feeling you would have a great answer for this question. I was optimising my code too, before I called it a night. My code evolved to use masks, and a combined sum minus the masked sum, but I was still using `DataFrame`s (because the real dataset has about 150 columns, and is in a `DataFrame`. I got a runtime about 250ms for 1000 rows.

Comment: @Kartik `2/3` of the original method? dataframes are known to be slow, so working with array data and of course the masking made sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong. I edited my original comment. I got about `2/3` between the original and the `sampler2`. Just using masks and precomputing the total sum provided a huge speedup. Dropping rows in the DataFrame was the most taxing.

Comment: @Kartik I see. What about `sampler4`? That seemed like the most performant one at my end. I guess something like sample1-4 at your end with a nice graph as you had posted originally in the question would be a nice view, just to see all at one place in one graph.

Comment: `sampler4` has the most performance. I'll edit my question to include the graphs from all versions of `sampler`. Usually I knock together a MWE for algorithms like this, and post a question here if I think I could use some extra help and if the question would interest some members. Then I continue optimising my MWE, till I am satisfied with the performance, or I tire. It was obvious to use masks (it eliminates the second `DF`, and removes the `loc` enlargement and the `drop`), so I did, and called it a night. And in the morning, you beat had the fastest code!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rewrite this while loop to do it in a single pass:

```
while True:
    choice = np.random.choice(df.index, 1, replace=False, p=df['samp_prob'])[0]
    samps.loc[choice, 'weight'] = df.loc[choice, 'weight']
    df.drop(choice, axis=0, inplace=True)
    df['samp_prob'] = df['weight']/df['weight'].sum()
    if samps['weight'].sum() >= 0.6:
        break
```

to something more like:

```
n = len(df.index)
ind = np.random.choice(n, n, replace=False, p=df["samp_prob"])
res = df.iloc[ind]
i = (res.cumsum() >= 0.6).idxmax()  # first index that satisfies .sum() >= 0.6
samps = res.iloc[:i+1]
```

*The key parts are that choice can take multiple elements (indeed the entire array) whilst still respecting the probabilities. The cumsum allows you to cut off after passing the 0.6 threshold.*

---

In this example you can see that the array is randomly chosen, but that 4 is most likely chosen nearer the top.

```
In [11]: np.random.choice(5, 5, replace=False, p=[0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6])
Out[11]: array([0, 4, 3, 2, 1])

In [12]: np.random.choice(5, 5, replace=False, p=[0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6])
Out[12]: array([3, 4, 1, 2, 0])

In [13]: np.random.choice(5, 5, replace=False, p=[0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6])
Out[13]: array([0, 4, 3, 1, 2])

In [14]: np.random.choice(5, 5, replace=False, p=[0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6])
Out[14]: array([4, 3, 0, 2, 1])

In [15]: np.random.choice(5, 5, replace=False, p=[0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6])
Out[15]: array([4, 2, 3, 0, 1])

In [16]: np.random.choice(5, 5, replace=False, p=[0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6])
Out[16]: array([3, 4, 2, 0, 1])
```

*Note: The replace=False, ensures the probabilities are "reweighed" in the sense that it can't be picked again.*

Comment: Can you point to the source which proves that `numpy.random.choice` reweighs exactly like the algorithm in the question? There are 2 ways this can be done, one is to just drop the element already chosen and the associated probability, and continue with the rest without renormalization. The other is to renormalize, which is the correct way to resample using non-parametric conditional probabilities. I can prove that without renormalization, the result will be biased (items with lower initial probabilities will be discriminated against). You can see it by renormalizing the example in your answer.

Comment: To clarify, elements with lower probabilities should be picked rarely. But renormalization ensures the probabilities increase. In a 3 element example with probabilities [0.6, 0.3, 0.1], if the first element is selected, new probabilities are [0.75, 0.25], which changes the odds of selection as compared to [0.3, 0.1].

Comment: As per the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx), `numpy.random.choice` only reweighs when it fails to find enough unique indices to satisfy the passed size. This is not correct for a true conditional sampling, therefore, I cannot accept your answer.